# How can we transform `functools.partial` into a decorator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parameter-passing, decorator, signature

There is a tool in the `functools` library named `partial`.

`functools.partial` allows us to specify some of the inputs a function without specifying all of them.

You can transform ...
`funky_function(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5)`
into something like...
`funky_function(1, 2, x3, x4, x5)`

That is...

- Input argument `x1` gets assigned the number `1`
- Input argument `x2` gets assigned the  number `2`
- Inputs `x3`, `x4`, `x5` are still ***not*** assigned anything.

```python
from functools import *
from inspect import *

def funky_function(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, /):
    return ", ".join(" ".join(str(x).split()) for x in [x1, x2, x3, x4, x5])

funky_function = partial(funky_function, 1, 2)

result = funky_function(3, 4, 5)

print("return value from `funky_function(3, 4, 5)` is:", result)
print("signature of `funky_function` is:", signature(funky_function))
```

My question is, how do we make a decorator?

```python
@partialize(1, 2)
def funky_function(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, /):
    return ", ".join(" ".join(str(x).split()) for x in [x1, x2, x3, x4, x5])

result = funky_function(3, 4, 5)
```

Look at the function signature below of `partial.partial(func)`:

```python
functools.partial(func, /, *args, **keywords)
```

The function is the left and the arguments on the right.

The following two pieces of code are equivalent:

```python
@decorate(1, 2)
def f():
   pass
###################################
def f():
   pass
f = decorate(1, 2)(f)
```

So, `partial` is not a good decorator if you want to enter arguments first, and enter the function second.

How do we make a decorator which takes in the arguments first, and later accepts the function to-be-decorated?

Comment: I'm a little confused: why would you want to write a function with N parameters and then decorate it so that some become irrelevant? It seems to me that if you wanted some thing like this you would write `def main_func(x1, x2, ... xn): ...` and then write `def func(...): return main_func(<relevant params>)`

Comment: @philosofool One potential application (but not the only one) is to use the value of a variable when the function is defined instead of when the function is called. For example, you could decorate a function so that `radius` is passed in as input where we use the value of `radius` just before the function was defined instead of the value of `radius` much later, when the function is called.

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following works:

```python
from functools import *
from inspect import *

def partialize(*args, **kwargs):
    def partialize_helper(old_func):
        new_func = partial(old_func, *args, **kwargs)
        return new_func
    return partialize_helper

@partialize(1, 2)
def funky_function(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, /):
    return ", ".join(" ".join(str(x).split()) for x in [x1, x2, x3, x4, x5])

##########################################################################

funky_function = partialize(1, 2)(funky_function)

##########################################################################

result = funky_function(3, 4, 5)
print("valued returned by funky_function(3, 4, 5)".ljust(50), result)
print("str(funky_function) ==".ljust(50), str(funky_function))
print("Signature == ".ljust(50), signature(funky_function))
```

Console output is as follows:

```
valued returned by funky_function(3, 4, 5)         1, 2, 3, 4, 5
str(funky_function) ==                             functools.partial(<function funky_function at 0x000001C99759E200>, 1, 2)
Signature ==                                       (x3, x4, x5, /)
```